# JPA ManyToMany - Always create a new value in the table even if the value exists

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm going trough some trouble. I am coding the back-end of a website in spring and I am using a Rest API.
I created two classes that are the relation "ManyToMany". 
The first class is "StateOfArt" and the second is "Tag".
When I start the server , I post 2 StateOfArt in Json (I'm using Insomnia) and it's working pretty well. I mean The two StateOfArt are in my DB. The problem is that Tags are duplicated even if the two StateOfArt have the same tags.

Here is an example:
I'm posting two StateOfArt in Json and this is ma DB:

[My table StateOfArt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAlff.png)

[My table Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R539Z.png)

[My Join table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3jSl.png)

I would like to have this in my join table:

1 1

1 2

2 1

2 2

And I would like to not have the redundancy in the table tag.

Is it possible to help me ?

Here the code of my two classes:

```
@Entity(name = "StateOfArt")
public class StateOfArt {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String date;
    private ArrayList<String> co_author;
    private String theabstract;

    //@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.ALL
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "state_of_art_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "stateofart_id"),//, referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))//, referencedColumnName = "id"))
    //@JsonIgnore
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public StateOfArt(){}

    public StateOfArt(Integer id, String author, String title, String date,ArrayList<String> co_author,String theabstract, HashSet<Tag> tags){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author =author;
        this.date =date;
        this.co_author = co_author;
        this.theabstract = theabstract;
        //this.articles = articles;
        this.tags = tags;

    }



    //Getters and Setters are here
}

@Entity(name = "Tag")
@Table(name = "tag_for_stateofart")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String name;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<StateOfArt> stateofarts = new HashSet<>();

    public Tag() {}

    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Tag tag = (Tag) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, tag.name);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are creating the same tag again. Check if tag with that name exists in DB, if yes, load it from Tag table.

Comment: How could I do that knowing that I’m using a JSON to enter a new data ?

Comment: Check if tag with that name exists in DB, if not, it is new

Comment: ok but how am I supposed to do that when I use a Json to enter a new data ?

Answer (score 0):

It must be a problem with tags table in your your database.
When you create the table you should specify column name in tags table to have unique values.

Comment: when I put @NaturalID on the top of name, I got this error when I try to post the second StateOfArt:

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Machine Learning' for key 'UK_t64dms8c1we9nmkfs5nub029r'